# Kotlin - I cannot get the same distance accuracy as Google maps

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, distance

I'm using Google Places api in my app which calculate the distance between 2 address,
the problem is that I get less distance than in google maps.

I cannot get the same accuracy as Google maps, 
Most of the time distance is shorter than the result from Google Maps

```
private fun SetupPlacesAutocompleteFun() {
    val _autocompletFragment1 = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaces1) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
    _autocompletFragment1.setPlaceFields(_placesFields)
    _autocompletFragment1.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object:PlaceSelectionListener{
        override fun onPlaceSelected(p1: Place) {
            _adrees1 = p1.latLng!!
            _adressString1 = p1.address!!
        }
        override fun onError(p1: Status) {
            Toast.makeText(this@GooglePlaces_Activity,"status "+p1.statusMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
    val _autocompletFragment2 = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentPlaces2) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
    _autocompletFragment2.setPlaceFields(_placesFields)
    _autocompletFragment2.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object :PlaceSelectionListener{
        override fun onPlaceSelected(p2: Place) {
            _adress2 =p2.latLng!!
            _adressString2 = p2.address!!
        }

        override fun onError(p2: Status) {
            Toast.makeText(this@GooglePlaces_Activity,"status "+p2.statusMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}

private fun InitPlacesFun() {
    Places.initialize(this,getString(R.string.Places_api))
    _placcesClint = Places.createClient(this)
}
```

```
fun TestButtonFun () {
    button.setOnClickListener() {
        var _loc:Location= Location("start")
        _loc.latitude = _adrees1.latitude
        _loc.longitude = _adrees1.longitude
        var _loc2:Location= Location("start")
        _loc2.latitude = _adress2.latitude
        _loc2.longitude = _adress2.longitude

        dist = (round(((_loc.distanceTo(_loc2).toDouble()/1000))*100) /100).toDouble()
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
var _Lat1 = _adrees1.latitude
var _Lat2 = _adress2.latitude
var _Long1 = _adrees1.longitude
var _Long2 = _adress2.longitude
var _LatRes = _Lat1 - _Lat2
var _longRes = _Long1 - _Long2

var R = 6371000f; // Radius of the earth in m
var dLat = _LatRes * Math.PI / 180f;
var dLon = _longRes * Math.PI / 180f;
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(_Lat1 * Math.PI / 180f) * Math.cos(_Lat2 * Math.PI / 180f) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
var c = 2f * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
 dist = R* c
```

Comment: use direction api to calculate distance between two locations i.e source and destination exact same as google map..

Answer (score 0):

You get less distance because you're calculating the radial distance and not the actual route distance.

Try calculating the distance using google directions API.

You can see the difference between radial distance (orange) and actual distance (blue) in the image[image]